# How to write interfaces to handle disparate concepts

Tags: oop, interface

I've always had trouble understanding how to abstract interfaces in such a way to include the overall effect of them but still deal with specifics:

e.g.,

```
interface iAudio 
{
    iInput input;
}
```

where iInput could be an input from various things(soundcard, file, etc...).

iAudio doesn't care where it's input comes from as long as it can get the data. So iInput abstracts the input. I'm fine up to this point. I can have different things that implement iInput to plug into but it seems difficult to figure out what to do after this point.

I obviously can write code that does stuff like `if (input is InputFile) ...` but that seems counter productive. (but this is the way that makes sense to me)

The other way I know how, but seems to be difficult for me, is to try and have iInput have the appropriate methods to get the data, e.g.,

```
interface iInput
{
    byte[] GetData();
}
```

and then have different classes implement this such as InputFile or InputSoundcard. It seems too abstract though and doesn't offer a lot of ability to do anything. (Maybe I can get the data but with InputFile I need to specify the filename while InputSoundcard would be other device specific information. Here then, I would end up still using the first case.

Maybe this is basically the right way to do it? It doesn't feel right. Hopefully my examples are clear enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The interface iInput is correct for me. I would like to react to what you said, which appears to be the only real problem for you :

"Maybe I can get the data but with InputFile I need to specify the filename while InputSoundcard would be other device specific information"

Yes. But is that *method*-specific information, or *instance*-specific information ? For me, the getData() method without arguments is totally acceptable, and every implementation will use whatever parameters are available in the attributes of the instance.

So, yes it's the right way to do it, or at least I think so :)

Comment: It seems though that if you don't design your interface to the best of it's ability you can run into trouble in the future.  What if the filename only needs changing? If you only allow changes in the constructor then you need to create a new object, which has a performance hit compared to just updating a string.

Comment: If the underlying file changes, what possible state in the input instance could be worth preserving?

Comment: That's why you use setter and getters on attributes. I used the constructor as an example, but there are more ways : properties in c#, get/set in java are the usual patterns, and who know what else in other languages. All that matters is that those parameters aren't in the responsability scope of the getData() method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you want an interface like that, is because the audio code doesn't need to care about the kind of input.

The doesn't go away, but it is outside that class.

At some point there is some code that selects some input, but isn't all mixed up with the audio code.

**Update:**

There are really many ways to go about the design of a specific application. It takes time to know how to deal with it, and there is not guarantee to learn it. Also remember, there will be mistakes, there is no way around it :)

Check this SOLID ebook - http://lostechies.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/pablos_solid_ebook.pdf, it helps.

Comment: I understand that, but at some point one needs to deal with the specifics. What if the device is changed? Then what? What if you need to update some device parameters? Do you start over from scratch? What if you need to display information about the input? If it is a file or device?

Comment: "What if you need to display information about the input?". You'd have a GetDisplayInformation() method in the interface. This way each input deals with the specific on how to do so. That's not the only way to go about it, but it wouldn't still be in something like IAudio.

Comment: What if the device is changed + what if you need to update some device parameters? without knowing the specifics, it'd seem you'd want to have some UI elements that are directly associated to each type of input you have (as you need to display the device specific options in the UI, but you also wouldn't want all the UI code to mix up with the rest). Another option is to have some mapping of device x device sub type, as you could have a subset of related devices that all really need the same parameters / in that case an interface  for those may be in order as well.

Comment: What if you need to update some device parameters? Do you start over from scratch? As you need UI x type, you could have the UI know about those instances, so a change in the UI updates directly the device sub type specific instance. Another way is to put it through some intermediary, that still allows to have device specific update events.